# Sending SIGUSR1 IPC in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, posix, ipc

I have the following NodeJS code:

```
setInterval(function() {}, 1e6);
process.on('SIGUSR1', function() {
    console.log('Got a signal');
});
```

In Unix I *should* be able to use `kill -s SIGUSR1 1234` to send this signal.  Windows doesn't have a `kill` command, I can see that Powershell does but it doesn't seem to have a -s like option.

```
NAME
    Stop-Process

SYNTAX
    Stop-Process [-Id] <int[]> [-PassThru] [-Force] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Stop-Process -Name <string[]> [-PassThru] [-Force] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Stop-Process [-InputObject] <Process[]> [-PassThru] [-Force] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    spps
    kill


REMARKS
    Get-Help cannot find the Help files for this cmdlet on this computer. It is displaying only partial help.
        -- To download and install Help files for the module that includes this cmdlet, use Update-Help.
        -- To view the Help topic for this cmdlet online, type: "Get-Help Stop-Process -Online" or
           go to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113412.
```

So, how to I send a `SIGUSR1` signal in Windows?

Comment: You don't.  There's no such thing as a signal in Windows.  Use another form of IPC.

Comment: OK, good to know.  Basically, there is no was to use this code then?  I can send `SIGINT` to it by pressing `Ctrl + C`.

Comment: Yes, the C runtime emulates SIGINT, and also provides support for raise() but does not provide signal-based IPC.  Now that I think of it, it *is* possible that Node.js provides some sort of signal emulation of its own, though I think it unlikely.  You could check the Node.js documentation, or perhaps a Node.js expert will chime in here.

Comment: Cheers, if I find something then I'll post it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was already mentioned Windows does not support UNIX signals.

But, SIGUSR1 is used in nodejs for starting the debugger on an already running process, if this is the functionality you were after, you could use the undocumented api:
**process._debugProcess(pid);**

This will start the debugger on the process.